# How to get MyPeerNodeEndpoint | aws managedblockchain get-node | step 3

Tags: amazon-web-services, hyperledger-fabric, aws-cli, amazon-managed-blockchain

I am trying to setup hyperledger fabric blockchain network using amazon managed blockchain following [this guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/managed-blockchain/latest/managementguide/get-started-create-client.html). In the step 3, I need `MyPeerNodeEndpoint` to create `docker_compose_cli.yaml` . For this, I executed this command `aws managedblockchain get-node --network-id n-zzz --member-id m-zzzz`. It reports the following error,

```
usage: aws [options] <command> <subcommand> [<subcommand> ...] [parameters]
To see help text, you can run:
  aws help
  aws <command> help
  aws <command> <subcommand> help
aws: error: argument --node-id is required
```

Where can I find this `node-id` ?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `--network-id n-zzz --member-id m-zzzz` are correct, you can get  the list of nodes available using [list-nodes](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/managedblockchain/list-nodes.html):

```
aws managedblockchain list-nodes --network-id n-zzz --member-id m-zzzz
```

The output of the command will contain "configuration properties for each node", one of which is the **node-id**.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I am getting empty response,
$ aws managedblockchain list-nodes --network-id n-zzz --member-id m-zzzz --region us-east-1
{
    "Nodes": []
}
Should I follow step 5 before step 3 and step 4. [   https://docs.aws.amazon.com/managed-blockchain/latest/managementguide/get-started-create-client.html    ]

Comment: @Gurunath Are you sure that `--network-id n-zzz --member-id m-zzzz` are correct? Maybe they are in different region or account that you try, or don't exist?

Comment: Yes. I am getting output for list-members and get-member.
`aws managedblockchain list-members --network-id n-zzz --region us-east-1 ==> {"Members": [{"Status": "AVAILABLE","CreationDate": "2020-07-21T09:02:20.106Z","IsOwned": true,"Id": "m-zzzz","Name": "org1"}]}`

Comment: @Gurunath So maybe you don't have any nodes. Have you used [create-node](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/managedblockchain/create-node.html) to make some?

Comment: No. That is why I am asking, should I follow step 5 in this document [https://docs.aws.amazon.com/managed-blockchain/latest/managementguide/get-started-create-client.html] before step 3 and step 4.

Comment: @Gurunath That would be my try. This would also explain why `list-nodes` returns empty list - there are no nodes to return.

Answer (score 0):

It works for me If I do step 5 before step 3 and step 4 in this [this guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/managed-blockchain/latest/managementguide/get-started-create-network.html)